# How to convert time to a encoded/encrypted string like G7C In PHP

Tags: php, json, base64, decode

i have a very different question,
We want to convert php strtotime("now"); to an encoded or encrypted form which looks like `"G7C5w3hJ9nR+uI0i/Awi1Auz/nw+Eu"`
same as this, not different.
I have codes to decode this encoded or encrypted string.
Here is the codes :

```
$lol = "G7C5w3hJ9nR+uI0i/Awi1Auz/nw+Eu";
$lol = trim($lol);
   
$default = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
$custom = "BSeI0grQ9Cmt/1oduh8AsF23wvZjpfGENx+n5JPMRYLDWqlVXy7zTHicO4UkKba6";
        
$lolec = base64_decode(strtr($lol, $custom, $default));
        
$lol = json_decode($lolec, true);
$date=@date_create($lol["date"]);
print_r( $date );
```

it will give you this output :-

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2021-03-25 06:38:46.000000 [timezone_type] => 1 [timezone] => +00:00 )
```

Here you can see we have decoded that string and we got date 2021-03-25 06:38:46.00000

But The Question is how is this string `"G7C5w3hJ9nR+uI0i/Awi1Auz/nw+Eu"` is encoded or encrypted? How can we make string like this?
I have some more strings like these, all are similar just some middle characters are changed, here are these :

```
G7C5w3hJ9nR+uI0i/AuToIpi/Aw+Eu
it will give you date 2021-02-28 04:46:56.000000
```

You can see nothing is changed in these 2 strings, just middle chracters are changed. We want to make the same string like this in php or golang. Anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the exact opposite process :

```
$default = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
$custom  = "BSeI0grQ9Cmt/1oduh8AsF23wvZjpfGENx+n5JPMRYLDWqlVXy7zTHicO4UkKba6";

$json = '{"date":"@1616654326"}';
$json64 = base64_encode($json);
$encoded = strtr($json64, $default, $custom);
$encoded = rtrim($encoded, '=');

var_dump($encoded); // string(30) "G7C5w3hJ9nR+uI0i/Awi1Auz/nw+Eu"
```

For a given timestamp :

```
$timestamp = '1614487616';
$array = ['date' => '@' . $timestamp];

$json = json_encode($array);
$json64 = base64_encode($json);
$encoded = strtr($json64, $default, $custom);
$encoded = rtrim($encoded, '=');
var_dump($encoded); // string(30) "G7C5w3hJ9nR+uI0i/AuToIpi/Aw+Eu"
```